# Getting AccountNotInitialized error when creating metadata account

Tags: anchor, anchor-spl, mpl-token-metadata

The Metadata and MasterEdition accounts are created using the `create_metadata_accounts_v3` and `create_master_edition_v3` instructions.

For some reason anchor expects them to already be initialized. Is there a workaround for this?

This check is avoided when using `AccountInfo` and `UncheckedAccount`

Comment: If you add `init` to the metadata account attribute, does that fix it? `#[account(init, ...)]`

Comment: no, this will lead to another error as I will be the one initializing it thus assign my program as the owner and that's another issue because `metadata_account` is supposed to be owned by `Metadata Program`